# Is there a way to expand the dropdown menu content upwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I would like to use an accordion inside a bootstrap dropdown with up direction ("dropup") and make the menu expand upwards.

I managed to setup the "accordion" inside the dropdown as you can see in the code example.

Here is the html

```
<div class="dropup" id="dropdownUp">
            <button
              class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
              type="button"
              id="btnGroup"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Dropdown
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroup" id="dmenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item keepopen" href="#c_1" data-toggle="collapse">Category 1</a>
              <ul class="collapse" id="c_1" data-parent="#dmenu">
                <li>Child 1-1</li>
                <li>Child 1-2</li>
                <li>Child 1-3</li>
              </ul>
              <a class="dropdown-item keepopen" href="#c_2" data-toggle="collapse">Category 2</a>
              <ul class="collapse" id="c_2" data-parent="#dmenu">
                <li>Child 2-1</li>
                <li>Child 2-2</li>
              </ul>
              <a class="dropdown-item keepopen" href="#c_3" data-toggle="collapse">Category 3</a>
              <ul class="collapse" id="c_3" data-parent="#dmenu">
                <li>Child 3-1</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropdownUp').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    if ($(e.clickEvent.target).hasClass('keepopen')) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  $('#dropdownUp').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu .collapse.show').collapse('hide');
  });
});
```

Here the link to the example

https://jsbin.com/cirejudipu/edit?html,js,output

The problem is, when the collapse expands, the dropdown menu goes over the button. Is there a way to make the accordion and the dropdown menu expand upwards? Thank you.

Comment: the menu is not infront of the button for me after expanding, at what moment should the menu be infront of the button?

Comment: The issue is that when opening the dropdown, the content's height is increased by 32px for each element. It doesn't respect your collapsible element inside of it. One way would be to just use jQuery and make it apply your own formula while keeping Bootstrap's styling.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the transform/rotate CSS property to force the element to turn upside down. you may need to use the same property on the contents to flip them right side up. I've used this on animated CSS/JS apps as well as on flipping entire canvas projects sideways.

here is the line of CSS

`transform: rotate(180deg);`

let me know if that helps